# How can I record an electron app session with puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, record, e2e-testing

I want to use puppeteer to record my tests in an electron app(**not in regular browser like chrome/firefox**).

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Related answer on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58213258/how-to-use-puppeteer-core-with-electron) / [puppeteer issue](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/4655). PS for the future google first please

Comment: this is not my question