# Failed to launch the browser process! spaw | Puppeteer / Electron

Tags: node.js, electron, puppeteer

I tried to change it with the args and ignoreDefaultArgs too.

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ executablePath, headless: false, args: [
    '--disable-gpu',
    '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
    '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
    '--no-first-run',
    '--no-sandbox',
    '--no-zygote',
    '--single-process',
],
ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--disable-extensions']                                                  
})
```

Still:

Failed to launch the browser process!
spawn C:\ProgramFiles\AppName\resources\app.asar\node_modules\puppeteer.local-chromium\win64-950341\chrome-win\chrome.exe ENOENT

EDIT:

package.json

```
{
  "name": "AppName",
  "productName": "AppName",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "description",
  "main": "src/app/main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "electron": "electron .",
    "build-installer": "electron-builder"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "AppName",
    "win": {
      "target": "nsis",
      "icon": "src/app/icon.png"
    },
    "nsis": {
      "installerIcon": "src/app/install_icon.ico",
      "uninstallerIcon": "src/app/uninstall_icon.ico",
      "uninstallDisplayName": "AppName",
      "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true,
      "oneClick": false
    }
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "electron": "^16.0.8",
    "electron-builder": "^22.14.5",
    "puppeteer": "^13.1.2",
    "puppeteer-core": "^13.1.3"
  }
}
```

If I try to build I must remove "electron" and "electron-builder" so this is optional.

Comment: Have you properly installed puppeteer? What is your setup (package.json, config, launch script, etc...) ?

Comment: @Seblor I added my package.json. If I add my script etc. I guess it will be too long

Comment: If I tried to start it with "npm run electron" it's working. But if I install it with the installer the message comes up

Comment: Alright you are using Electron with Puppeteer. Is it all production builds that fail, or just the installed program ?

Comment: Only the installed program

Comment: Have you read this and tried the solutions provided: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58213258/how-to-use-puppeteer-core-with-electron ?

Comment: I tried to use it. I didn't understand how it works. I got a renderer.js file for the dom manipulation and main.js for the electron build. I can't chat with you cause I got only 3 reps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Failed to launch the browser process puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59979188/error-failed-to-launch-the-browser-process-puppeteer)